# Strange characters on display st7920

Tags: display

My Display is showing texts with strange characters in Chinese. how can i fix this

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
        #include <Arduino.h>
        #include <U8g2lib.h>
        
        #ifdef U8X8_HAVE_HW_SPI
        #include <SPI.h>
        #endif
        #ifdef U8X8_HAVE_HW_I2C
        #include <Wire.h>
        #endif
        
          U8G2_ST7920_128X64_F_SW_SPI u8g2(U8G2_R0, /* clock=*/ 18, /* data=*/ 23, /* CS=*/ 5, /* reset=*/ 22); // ESP32
                  
        
        
        void setup(void) {
          u8g2.begin();
        }
        
        void loop(void) {
          u8g2.clearBuffer();                   // clear the internal memory
          u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_ncenB08_tr);   // choose a suitable font
          u8g2.drawStr(0,10,"Hello World!");    // write something to the internal memory
          u8g2.sendBuffer();                    // transfer internal memory to the display
          delay(1000);  
        }
```

Comment: run simple "hello world" code first

Comment: Your source is far too big to be examined. Please step back and write the most simple test program that still reveals the issue.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to print uft8

Comment: I put a simple code like hello world and still the same error

Comment: Have you double-checked your wiring, and that the display uses SPI? Do you have an oscilloscope to watch the transmitted signals, at least the initializing ones?